# Is there a known timeout problem related to Braintree hosted fields checkout and Analytics.GA4.PurchaseComplete?

Tags: braintree

Grasping at straws; there is a very intermittent and tough to reproduce issue my team is facing since we rolled out an implementation of Braintree checkout for credit cards. It's working great but less than 1% of orders fail to initialize Braintree's checkout and reach the gateway.

Logging shows a common denominator seems to be "**Analytics.GA4.PurchaseComplete**" happening right after the error. Other than that we can't see what's going wrong or timing out.

The step in which it seems to break is in the version ID for the INIT:

```
Braintree: INIT Start
Braintree: INIT Respond
Braintree: ver-3.96.0
Braintree: DC {"correlation_id":" // etc etc.
```

Suggestions?

Further context: this is a custom implementation (hosted fields) not their checkout UI. I'm not a dev myself so you might need to ELI5 a little, sorry.

Tried third party user monitoring tools and replays. We see the broken sessions and clicks and a script error in there somewhere but can't capture the console message.

We tried forcing the script to reload the form, that didn't help.

Telemetry logs give us the GA4 message but that's it so far.